# User defaults Only Working On Restart

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I am trying to implement a light and dark mode in my application. In the `settingsViewController` I have these lines of code:

```
//Sets user default for colour
let lightMode = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "lightMode")

//UISegment control for user to pick colour
@IBOutlet var colourSegment: UISegmentedControl!

//Updates lightMode based on user selection
@IBAction func didChangeColours(_ sender: Any) {

    if colourSegment.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "lightMode")
    } else if colourSegment.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "lightMode")
    }

}
```

In my `entryViewController`, in my `viewDidLoad`, I have:

```
let lightMode = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "lightMode")

if lightMode == false {
    Colours.darkMode()
}

customisations()
```

The issue that I'm running into is that for some reason, my application is only changing it's colour scheme after I restart it. That is, if the user selects the `darkIndex` of the `colourSegment`, the application only updates the colour after I restart. I am wondering what is the solution for this.

Comment: As you said, you only *read and set* the color in your viewDidLoad. You need to put the same logic into the `didChangeColor:` function.

Comment: Could you please expand?

Comment: When you click the segmented control you just store the value in UserDefaults, but you don’t update the UI there. You only update it in `viewDidLoad`. What you need to do is put that same logic (setting the color of the ui) in the `didChangeColours:` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the line -

```
//Sets user default for colour
let lightMode = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "lightMode")
```

this line is not for setting the Userdefaults but instead it gets the UserDefaults. Since you use it before setting the default Value, it doesn't reflect the right segmented choice. So your setting part is correct and you should fetch the value only after you have set it.

Also in your entryViewController, instead of using it from settingsVC, do below -

```
//get from UserDefaults
let lightMode = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "lightMode")

//Compare the previous fetched value
if lightMode == false {
    Colours.darkMode()
}

//This function sets the colour for the elements
colours()
```

Comment: How would I change it?

Comment: Your change code in the didChangeColors of the segmented control is correct and that will save the User Defaults

Comment: Would you mind explaining what you mean by "this line is not for setting the USerdefaults but instead it gets the userdefaults. Since you use it before setting ti, it doesn't reflect the right segmented choice."

Comment: So that line of code is to fetch the value from user defaults with the key "lightMode". So what happens is when you open the settings for the first time, there will be no value in it so always false. And this gets saved in your settingsVC.lightMode i am assuming. Now when the user sets it, you save it in userdefaults which is fine. Now in your entryViewController you can get it from userdefaults so you will get the right value. but if you get it from settingsVC.lightMode, since its an old value you dont get it right in the next VC

Comment: So I tried implanting your code and it still didn't work. Do you have any more suggestions?

Comment: So what is the issue now and can you add the updated code in your post

Comment: The issue is that it still is not updating unless I close my application

Comment: Ok so after you do the settings, what next do you do. How are you checking if its updating? in the editVC or somewhere else?

Comment: I am not calling the `Colours.darkMode` in the `settingViewController`, only in the `entryViewController`

Comment: so then it will only update once you open the `entryViewController`. If you want to open immediately, you need to put that code as soon as your settings is changed

Comment: Ok so I have called it in the `settingsViewController`, and it is working. But now the problem is that when I restart the application, I lose the colour scheme.

Comment: When you restart the app are you getting the color scheme from preference? i.e getting lightMode and then setting colors?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are assigning the `lightMode` value ONLY 1 time during init, you don't reflect the changes to the variable, so it will always be that value

To always get the lastest value, use this:

```
let lightMode: Bool {
   get {
       return UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "lightMode")
   }
}
```

Also, you should call the color change immediatelly after change the value

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are returning to your `entryViewController` from your `settingsViewController`; Since you are returning to an existing view controller instance, the code in `viewDidLoad` is not executed when you return.

Move the code to `viewWillAppear`; This way your code will execute prior to the view controller appearing even when you return to the existing instance:

```
func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    let lightMode = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "lightMode")

    if lightMode == false {
        Colours.darkMode()
    }
}
```